# How do I ensure my rafters are safe from condensation behind the insulation?

Tags: roof, attic, condensation, renovation, attic-conversion

I am undertaking a loft conversion currently and am soon wanting to put insulation at rafter level.  I have chosen 'Superquilt' (a aluminium, fibre composite layer) and PIR backed plasterboard (23mm PIR with 9mm plasterboard).  I am afraid though that behind all this condensation will be building up and seeping into my roof rafters and rotting them. 
I have bituminous roof felt and tiles with 300mm centres.

Should I be worried and is there anything I can do (without taking the whole roof off!)?

[image: this is a photo of probably the worst it has gotten in its current state - i log temperature every few minutes for the past few days and the temperatures similar to out with humidity at generally 100%]

Comment: Have you considered putting insulation atop the existing roof deck instead of under it?

Comment: Do you mean on top of the rafters beneath the tiles? If so that would require removing the roof, so not really an option,

Comment: yeah, insulation on top has its advantages, but isn't always an option (especially for a roof covering that'd be such a chore to remove and replace)

Comment: Yeah, can't really do that, good idea though and would look good!